# WP8 - Display the photo i have taken in the control Image

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Title explains everything.
How should i do ?

I coded this :

```
Dim size As Windows.Foundation.Size
    Dim seq As CameraCaptureSequence
    Dim imageStream As New MemoryStream
    If PhotoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Back) Then
        Dim avalaibleSizeList As IReadOnlyList(Of Windows.Foundation.Size) = PhotoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back)
        size = avalaibleSizeList(0)
        Me.captureDevice = Await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, size)
    End If
    seq = captureDevice.CreateCaptureSequence(1)
    seq.Frames(0).CaptureStream = imageStream.AsOutputStream()
    Await captureDevice.PrepareCaptureSequenceAsync(seq)
    Await seq.StartCaptureAsync()
    imageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    Dim library As New MediaLibrary
    Dim picture As Picture = library.SavePictureToCameraRoll("PhotosIncidents", imageStream)
```

But what i am suppose to do now?

Comment: Display picture in image control no?Binding or set image.ImageSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `BitmapImage`, set it's source to your `imageStream`. Then put an `Image` control in XAML to display `BitmapImage` in your application :

```
Dim bitmapImage As BitmapImage
bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream)
MyImageControl.Source = bitmapImage
```

Note : I havent tested the code, but thats what I will try if I need to do the same.

Comment: Sorry for answer you late, i was very busy, didnt have time to test.
I tested it today and it works bro. Thx !
=> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: no problem, I just wonder if this actually work or not. Was considering to delete the answer if it doesn't work so that nobody get misguided later. Glad to know it work